# Which of the following is a great example of "drive a hard bargain"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrases, idioms-in-context

I have a following question and have just heard the answer is 1, not 4. (can't understand.) Pls explain why?

**Which of the following is a great example of "drive a hard bargain"?**

1. The price I paid for this apple watch is almost the same as the retail price.
2. This apple watch was a little expensive, but I think I got it at reasonable price.
3. This apple watch I paid for was so cheap, but now it doesn't work.
4. The price I paid for this apple watch is better than the retail price.

Comment: Welcome to the group! Does it say apple or Apple?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any of them are *good* examples, much less *great*. You'd have to ask the people that gave you the test to be sure.

But I suppose that number 1 really is the correct example, even if it isn't an obvious one.

The sentences mention "I" several times, while omitting the more significant person.
It was *the dealer* that drove the hard bargain, not *you*.
You tried to get a better price but the salesman barely budged from the original offer.